# Kinect input to Unity3d output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, unityscript

I'm creating the Game using "Kinect xbox 360" and Unity3d. I have created the link between Kinect and Unity so that the character in Unity3d do the same actions[Movements] that what we do from Kinect sensor.

**Now my question is how to take that actions[Movements] as input for UNITY3d?**

For Example: If I do up my Right hand the character will walk or run or jump whatever it's.

How can I check that Hand is Moved up in Script [ UnityScript or C# ]

For Example :

```
 if(GameObject.transform == "RightHand")
  {
     ------------------------
     ------------------------
  }
```

I searched out all sites through google but No result....

I have connected the Kinect through [ZIGFU](http://zigfu.com/) with Unity3d.

Lets see which Adroit will answer for this . . .!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that heavily depends on the gesture you want to check for. There also is an SDK that comes with some gestures to recognize. Have a look at the code: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/7747

An example: You want to check for a hand being held up. Get the object of a handbone and check if it stays over a certain value of the z axis for a couple of milliseconds or seconds.